# Problem with my cron in custom module in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I am unable to call cron into my model using this xml. Please suggest be a way.

app/code/local/Rkt/Crons/etc/config.xml

```
  <models>
        <cronscron>
            <class>Rkt_Crons_Model</class>
        </cronscron>                         
    </models>
</global>
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <cronscron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
              <model>cronscron/observer::setStatus</model>
            </run>
        </cronscron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

/app/code/local/Rkt/Crons/Model/Observer.php

```
 class Rkt_Crons_Model_Observer
{

   public function setStatus()
   { 

     Mage::log("WORKS!");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the job name so that it is different from the models sub-node

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <somecron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
              <model>cronscron/observer::setStatus</model>
            </run>
        </somecron>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, its working now.